# Domain filter in XML odoo 10

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

I have added a class operating.unit. In product.template I have added this as Many2one filed as operating_unit_id. In res.users I have referred this class as many2many fields operating_unit_ids. I need to filter product field such that only the product of current user's tagged operating units should be shown in drop down. I used domain as below. It's filtering out everything.

```
<field name="product_id"
domain="[('operating_unit_id','in', 'user_id.operating_unit_ids.ids')]"/>
```

However if I statically pass id as below it works fine.

```
<field name="product_id" domain="[('operating_unit_id','in', (3,4))]"/>
```

Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to use many2many field as a domain for filter ??

Comment: @ManishBohra Yes, you are right ! Is that possible ?

Comment: here you have to ensure the ids under user_id becomes correct

Comment: Yes, I checked in python(using self)... Current ids in user_id.operating_unit_ids are (1,2,3,4,5,6). 

I also found that it's directly checking the text(the exact text) instead of values. Any Idea ??

Answer (score 2):

Some days ago i also face this problem and didn't find appropriate solution. So, I suggest you apply this domain in python file instead of xml file.

```
domain="[('id', 'in', operating_unit_id and operating_unit_id[0] and "operating_unit_id[0][2] or False)]"
```

Comment: Thanks. 
    domain="[('id', 'in', operating_unit_ids[0][2])]"

This one filtered fine. 

But it works only when I change product in already saved lead. When I create fresh lead and try to drop down product it gives the following error. 

raise ValueError("Invalid domain term %r" % (leaf,))
ValueError: Invalid domain term (u'id', u'in', {u'code': u'EC', u'company_id': 1, u'name': u'Etisalat consumer'})

Now... the output format of many2many changes ???

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and compute your many2many field after you can apply domain.

```
<field name="product_id" domain="[('id','in',TEST and TEST[0][2])]"/>
```

**TEST** your many2many field name.
I hope it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness: at this link you'll find more detailed explanation about previous answers

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/complex-many2many-domains-in-views-41777